# Unauthorized when requesting a token from Azure App Service

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a simple web app that needs to call an Azure Function.

I've registered 2 apps in my Azure AD: one for my single page react application and another for my Azure Function.

[image: two app registrations]

The app for my azure function has an API exposed on it and a scope configured called `CallApi`.

[image: api and scope]

The app itself has authentication configured on it (easy auth), and the client id matches the API app registration within AAD:
[image: auth on app]

The app for my SPA has permission to request this scope and this is granted by default for all users.

[image: permissions for client]

I am able to successfully log users into my SPA and get an access token. I'm doing this with the use of the `@azure/msal-browser` and `@azure/msal-react` npm libraries, specifically:

```
<MsalAuthenticationTemplate interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect} authenticationRequest={{scopes: ["User.Read", "api://<redacted>/CallApi"]}} >
```

However, the access token that is returned only has these scopes: `['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read', 'email']` and not `api://<redacted>/CallApi`. So when I try to exchange my access token for a token by sending a POST request to `https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` it returns an unauthorized message.

How can I ensure that the `CallApi` scope is allow by my app?

Answer (score 0):

> So when I try to exchange my access token for a token by sending a POST request to `https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` it returns an unauthorized message.

Please ensure that the URL is correct as it should be in the format of `<app-url>/.auth/login/aad/callback` and note that the parameters are in the body of the HTTP POST request.

> However, the access token that is returned only has these scopes: `['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read', 'email']`

###### **openid**

If an app performs sign-in by using OpenID Connect, then it must request the openid scope. That is to say, the openid scope displays on the work account consent page as the “Sign you in” permission.

###### **email**

The email scope can work with the openid scope. As it gives the app access to the user’s primary email address in the form of the email claim. Where, the email claim is included in a token only if an email address is associated with the user account, which isn’t always the case.

###### **profile**

The profile scope can also work with the openid scope. This gives the app access to a substantial amount of information about the user. The information that it has access includes, the user’s given name, surname, preferred username, and object ID.

In the Microsoft ecosystem there are some high-privilege permissions that can be set to admin-restricted. This include:

- Firstly, read all user’s full profiles by using  **User.Read.All**
- Secondly, write data to an organization’s directory by using  **Directory.ReadWrite.All**
- Lastly, read all groups in an organization’s directory by using  **Groups.Read.All**

Please refer this [article](https://www.testpreptraining.com/tutorial/configuring-app-registration-permission-and-scopes/) for an example regarding the POST request regarding the Call API Scope.